# LUIS strange behavior

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

Recently I created a LUIS App for testing and see how it works.

As you can see in the next image, the Intent "Actividades" (sorry about spanish words) has all that utterances.

When I train LUIS and then test with words like "act" or "acti" it returns the Intent `Actividades`, which is fine. But, if I test the words "actividade" or "activida" (for example) it returns a `None` Intent (which has no utterrances).

Why does LUIS do this?

[image: LUIS Strange behavior...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publish the app, test the endpoint, then go to "Review endpoint utterances" in Luis.ai. The utterances that are mapped to None are probably there, indicated that LUIS wants to know which intent they should be mapped to. Map them to the correct intent, train, and publish again. Test the corrected version. It should be correct now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you note Microsoft's advice that you should always populate the 'None' intent with a collection of utterances that are completely off-topic, and the count of these should amount to at least 10% of all the other utterances... and as much as 20%. That's referred to in a number of places. They say if you leave None unpopulated, you'll possibly get the kind of response you describe here.